# Software to block access to certain programs at specific times?

Tags: productivity

I'm trying to increase my productivity and notice that I've been staying up late surfing the internet/playing games.

Since willpower is generally lacking at the end of the day, I'd like to find a software that can block specific programs during specific time windows.

The program needs to be password protected, and ideally it should be able to be a different password than my administrator password. That way I can make a separate longer password that I write down and put in a non easily accessible place so I cant just unlock the restrictions on a whim.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Free parental control software](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1882/free-parental-control-software)

Comment: Related/dupe: [Web blocker for Windows, to avoid procrastination?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/17210/web-blocker-for-windows-to-avoid-procrastination) // [Program that stops me from opening certain programs, on Windows 10](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/33813/program-that-stops-me-from-opening-certain-programs-on-windows-10) // [3rd party Windows/Mac software to log off computer after x minutes of use](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/34478/3rd-party-windows-mac-software-to-log-off-computer-after-x-minutes-of-use) ..

Comment: … [Software that locks out other software for a certain period of time](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/18030/185) // [“program blocker” which blocks programs for a specified amount of time](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/11352/185) and probably many more. Apart from that, some essential details are missing from your question: What OS should this be for? How much are you willing to spend on such a software?